# Why aren't third and fourth boxes in this cascading drop-downs javascript not populating?

Tags: javascript, cascading

Should be very simple cascading dropdowns, the the third and fourth dropdowns are populating.

Selection from first dropdown populates second dropdown as expected.  But selection from second dropdown does not impact third or fourth dropdown.

I'm sure I've missed something obvious but I can't find it.  Any help appreciated.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var clientPlus = {
      "Client A": {
        "Transactional": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        },
        "Monthly": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        }
      },
      "Client B": {
        "Transactional": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        },
        "Monthly": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        }
      },
      "Client C": {
        "Transactional": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        },
        "Monthly": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        }
      }
    }


    window.onload = function() {

      //Get html elements
      var clientSel = document.getElementById("clientSel");
      var invoicetypeSel = document.getElementById("invoicetypeSel");
      var payerSel = document.getElementById("payerSel");
      var sorbSel = document.getElementById("sorbSel");

      //Load clients
      for (var client in clientPlus) {
        clientSel.options[clientSel.options.length] = new Option(client, client);
      }

      //client Changed
      clientSel.onchange = function() {

        invoicetypeSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        payerSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        sorbSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
          return; // done

        for (var invoicetype in clientPlus[this.value]) {
          invoicetypeSel.options[invoicetypeSel.options.length] = new Option(invoicetype, invoicetype);
        }
      }
      //Invoice Type Changed
      invoicetypeSel.onchange = function() {

        payerSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        sorbSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
          return; // done

        for (var payer in clientPlus[this.value]) {
          payerSel.options[payerSel.options.length] = new Option(payer, payer);
        }
      }

      //Payer Changed
      payerSel.onchange = function() {
        sorbSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
          return; // done

        var sorbs = clientPlus[clientSel.value][invoicetypeSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < sorbs.length; i++) {
          sorbSel.options[sorbSel.options.length] = new Option(sorbs[i], sorbs[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select id="clientSel" size="1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Client:</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <select id="invoicetypeSel" size="1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Invoice Type:</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="payerSel" size="1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Payer Type:</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="sorbSel" size="1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Successful or Busted?</option>
    </select>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mbps1/bt9m3qoj/1/

Answer (score 1):

inside `invoicetypeSel.onchange`, your for is getting values from clientPlus[Second Value] you are forgetting to also supply the first value of your object.

```
for (var payer in clientPlus[clientSel.value][this.value]) {
    payerSel.options[payerSel.options.length] = new Option(payer, payer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The control conditions for both `for` cyles in `clientSel.onchange` and `invoiceTypeSel.onchange` are the same. In other words, they are iterating over the same key value pairs in both cases (i.e. `cientPlus[some ID]`). In the first case, when populating 'invoiceType' based on client selection, it is fine since you'll get an object with two attributes: Monthly and Transactional (each referencing an object), but in the second case, when you want to populate 'playerType', it's hardly satisfying to use the same cycle. Instead, you want to iterate over the object *one level deeper*: `clientPlus[some ID][whatever the selection for invoiceType was]`.

It should be noted however, that this data structure seems redundant. Values that are the same and repeating over and over would be better stored once only.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var clientPlus = {
      "Client A": {
        "Transactional": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        },
        "Monthly": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        }
      },
      "Client B": {
        "Transactional": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        },
        "Monthly": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        }
      },
      "Client C": {
        "Transactional": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        },
        "Monthly": {
          "Single": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Third Party": ["Successful", "Busted"],
          "Joint": ["Successful", "Busted"]
        }
      }
    }


    window.onload = function() {

      //Get html elements
      var clientSel = document.getElementById("clientSel");
      var invoicetypeSel = document.getElementById("invoicetypeSel");
      var payerSel = document.getElementById("payerSel");
      var sorbSel = document.getElementById("sorbSel");

      //Load clients
      for (var client in clientPlus) {
        clientSel.options[clientSel.options.length] = new Option(client, client);
      }

      //client Changed
      clientSel.onchange = function() {

        invoicetypeSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        payerSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        sorbSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
          return; // done

        for (var invoicetype in clientPlus[this.value]) {
          invoicetypeSel.options[invoicetypeSel.options.length] = new Option(invoicetype, invoicetype);
        }
      }
      //Invoice Type Changed
      invoicetypeSel.onchange = function() {

        payerSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first
        sorbSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
          return; // done

        for (var payer in clientPlus[clientSel.options[clientSel.selectedIndex].value][this.value]) {
          payerSel.options[payerSel.options.length] = new Option(payer, payer);
        }
      }

      //Payer Changed
      payerSel.onchange = function() {
        sorbSel.length = 1; // remove all options bar first

        if (this.selectedIndex < 1)
          return; // done

        var sorbs = clientPlus[clientSel.value][invoicetypeSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < sorbs.length; i++) {
          sorbSel.options[sorbSel.options.length] = new Option(sorbs[i], sorbs[i]);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="myform" id="myForm">
    <select id="clientSel" size="1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Client:</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>

    <select id="invoicetypeSel" size="1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Invoice Type:</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="payerSel" size="1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select Payer Type:</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <select id="sorbSel" size="1">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Successful or Busted?</option>
    </select>
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```